# MIPS: Finding average of 5 integers

Tags: assembly, mips

**Objective:** Using user input, find the average value using five registers.

**Example:** 1 3 2 9 4

**Output:** 3

Output is 3 because 3.8 is a decimal and I want it in integers

My goal is to not use array but I am having trouble adding all 5 registers:

```
.data
   prompt1: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt2: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt3: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt4: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt5: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   result: .asciiz "The average is: "

.text
main:
   #t0 - hold prompt1
   #t1 - hold prompt2
   #t2 - hold prompt3
   #t3 - hold prompt4
   #t4 - hold prompt5
   #t5 - hold sum from prompt1 to prompt5
   #t6 - hold the average value


   # Prompt the user to enter integer1.
   li $v0, 4        # syscall to print string
   la $a0, prompt1
   syscall

   # Read integer1
   li $v0, 5        # syscall to read an integer
   syscall
   move $t0, $v0        # move number to read into $t0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 2.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt2
   syscall

   # Read integer2
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t1, $v0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 3.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt3
   syscall

   # Read integer3
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t2, $v0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 4.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt4
   syscall

   # Read integer4
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t3, $v0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 5.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt5
   syscall

   # Read integer5
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t4, $v0
```

the part where I got my error

```
   # add all integers to $t5
   add $a0, $t0, $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4
   li $v0, 1
   syscall
```

continued...

```
   # Read the sum
   li $v0, 5
   syscall
   move $t5, $v0

   # Divide Sum / count
   div $t5, 5

   # retrieve it
   mflo $t6

   #print out the average
   move $a0, t6
   li $v0, 1
   la $a0, result
   syscall

exit:
   li $v0, 10
   syscall
```

I get an error message

> spim:(parser) syntax error on line 71 of ... 'add $a0, $t0, $t1, $t2,
>   $t3, $t4

Comment: Could someone please tell me what I did wrong? *(Correction)

Comment: Only a professor at a university would ask a student to write MIPS assembly to do this. Lol :)

Comment: `add $a0, $t0, $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4` <-- From where did you get the impression that this would be valid? Have you tried looking up `add` in a MIPS instruction set reference?

Comment: CPUs only understand instructions with defined structures, not like adding parameters forever like that

Comment: Does that mean, I have to use arrays to add multiple integers in MIPS? sorry I'm new to this language

Comment: No, you have to use a separate `add` (or `addu`) instruction for every `+` operator in your a+b+c+d+e expression.  The `add` instruction has exactly two inputs, and one output.

Comment: In other words, the assembly language has almost no expressions, you have fixed set of instructions available (implemented by the transistors in the HW of CPU), and you are building up SW from using those fixed instructions. Like you can do `add $1, $2, $3`, but you can't do `add $44, $2, $3`, because MIPS CPU has no register `$44` (only `$0` to `$31`). Whatever expression like 4+5 you have in source is being calculated during compilation, it's not part of final machine code, as for example `sb $5,4($6)` can have only single displacement immediate in the machine code, no way to encode 4 as 1+3

Comment: With MIPS assemblers and pseudo-instructions it's a bit more complicated, as you write in source `la $t4,some_symbol` and it actually compiles to different native non-pseudo instructions depending on the value of `some_symbol`, but with most of the other CPUs and their assemblers you have available only native instructions which gets compiled to their binary machine code counterparts 1:1 just like you wrote them in the source. And you can't build up new instruction for already existing CPU, it can do only what was designed and created by the CPU vendor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to add 5 integers, this is an improvised version of your code.

```
.data
   prompt1: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt2: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt3: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt4: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   prompt5: .asciiz " Please enter an integer: "
   result: .asciiz " The average is: "

.text
main:
   #t0 - hold prompt1
   #t1 - hold prompt2
   #t2 - hold prompt3
   #t3 - hold prompt4
   #t4 - hold prompt5
   #t5 - hold sum from prompt1 to prompt5
   #t6 - hold the average value


   # Prompt the user to enter integer1.
   li $v0, 4        # syscall to print string
   la $a0, prompt1
   syscall

   # Read integer1
   li $v0, 5        # syscall to read an integer
   syscall
   move $t0, $v0        # move number to read into $t0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 2.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt2
   syscall

   # Read integer2
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t1, $v0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 3.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt3
   syscall

   # Read integer3
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t2, $v0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 4.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt4
   syscall

   # Read integer4
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t3, $v0

   # Prompt the user to enter integer 5.
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt5
   syscall

   # Read integer5
   li $v0,5
   syscall
   move $t4, $v0

   # add all integers to $t5
   add $t5, $t0, $t1
   add $t5, $t5, $t2
   add $t5, $t5, $t3
   add $t5, $t5, $t4

   li $t6,5

   # Divide Sum / count
   div $t5, $t5, $t6

  

   #print out the average
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, result
   syscall

   move $a0, $t5     
   li $v0, 1        #prints average value
   syscall


exit:
   li $v0, 10
   syscall
```

Comment: You don't need 5 different copies of the prompt string.  All that prompt stuff kind of buries the important part (the four `add` instructions).  Also, you could just do one `add` after each syscall, even doing that in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean, I have to use arrays to add multiple integers in MIPS?

No, you can keep everything in registers, but you have to use a separate `add` (or `addu`) instruction for every `+` operator in your a+b+c+d+e expression.

**The `add` instruction has exactly two inputs, and one output.**

Basic [MIPS instruction-set reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).